# Program crash after trying to access and write to structure member

Tags: c, visual-studio, struct, fft

Working in Visual Studio in C and trying to do `fft` of some samples.
When I attempt writing some value to member of struct my program crash and I get error access violation writing location 0x00000000.

First, I tried to use [this](https://github.com/berndporr/kiss-fft) C code, but got errors:

```
kiss_fft_cpx *cx_in = new kiss_fft_cpx[nfft];  
kiss_fft_cpx *cx_out = new kiss_fft_cpx[nfft];
```

in this two lines. Okay there is no new in C. I tried to modify it but I can not do it. I tried

```
kiss_fft_cpx *cx_in[1024];
kiss_fft_cpx *cx_out[1024];
```

and few lines after i tried to pass some value with

```
cx_in[brojac]->r = i; // this is where program breaks
cx_in[brojac]->i = q;
```

from `kiss_fft.h` header file

```
typedef struct {
   kiss_fft_scalar r;
   kiss_fft_scalar i;
} kiss_fft_cpx;

typedef struct kiss_fft_state* kiss_f;

//beginning of main 
kiss_fft_cpx *cx_in[1024];
kiss_fft_cpx *cx_out[1024];

//after doing some sampling 
cx_in[brojac]->r = i; // this is where program crash
cx_in[brojac]->i = q;
```

Comment: `cx_in` is an array of pointers. You need to allocate memory for the storage of the data. Are you doing so? Please show this allocation.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial or book about memory allocation.

Comment: Answers below are correct, but you can also just do `kiss_fft_cpx cx_in[1024];` (i.e. remove the `*` to allocate an array of structs rather than an array of pointers to structs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cx_in` and `cx_out` are just pointers to an array of structs. You need to allocate the memory.

```
kiss_fft_cpx *cx_in = malloc(1024*sizeof(kiss_fft_cpx));
kiss_fft_cpx *cx_out = malloc(1024*sizeof(kiss_fft_cpx));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kiss_fft_cpx *cx_in = new kiss_fft_cpx[nfft];
```

In C++ this will allocate an array of structs. The analogous part in C is

```
struct kiss_fft_cpx *cx_in = malloc(nfft * sizeof(struct kiss_fft_cpx));
```

You can use this as

```
cx_in[brojac].r = i;  // where 0 <= brojac < nfft
```